# Update multiple diffrenet number in single query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one customer table in customer table i have 2 field accounts & status:

[image]

I need output like this:

[image]

I have 1000 accounts  and need update that 1000 number status=1.

In customer table 200 000 accounts but i have update selected 1000 accounts only. How i can update those selected accounts?

Comment: Hi there, I'm having difficulty understanding your question. Especially the last sentence. `In customer table 2 lakhs accounts but i have update selected 1000 accounts only how i can update that selected accounts.` What do you mean by "selected accounts"? (Also what is lakhs?)

Comment: Hi@TrebuchetMS,Here I means client give me 1000 account from that 2 lakhs records and say me change the status of that 1000 accounts

Comment: As you see, using Indian words like "lakh" confuse people. Please don't do that here.

Comment: Also, how does the client give you the accounts? A comma separated list? Something else? We're really not mind readers...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$sql = "select * from customer where 'selected account'";

//execute query

//after execute query you have get selected record after that loop that record and update all selected record
while(){
    $sql = "update customer set status='1' where id='id from selected record'";
    //execute query
}
```